# Two LEGO Powered Up engines with reverse direction

Tags: trains, powered-up

I have 2 LEGO 60197 City Passenger Trains and I would like to attach both sets together and run them on the same channel.

The problem with the current disposition of the bogies is that reversing the powered bogie is impractical. Is there a way to invert the direction of one of the engines in order to make them run together: one engine at the front the other at the rear in reverse mode?

Answer (score 2):

Th easiest solution is to just use port "B" on the rear engine and then turn the "B" side remote control panel 180 degrees.  They will then both go the same direction for "up" or "down". You may even find that having the rear motor 1 click lower than the front is advantageous so it isn't pushing too much in turns, trying to buckle the train.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the powered up smartphone app or the lego powered up remote to switch direction of a given motor.

If not you could use gears to reverse the direction of one of the axles. the motor would drive an axle which would gear onto the train wheel axle.